# PlanarAngle symbolic equalities return contradictory results

Tags: symbolic, geometry

```
PlanarAngle[OO->{A,B}]==PlanarAngle[OO->{B,A}]/.{OO->{0,0},A->{1,0},B->{1,1}}
```

> False

```
PlanarAngle[OO->{A,B}]==PlanarAngle[OO->{B,A}]/.{OO->{0,0},A->{x1,x2},B->{y1,y2}}
```

> True

It is contradiction

Comment: The funny thing is that on a fresh kernel (`Quit[]`) the later does not fully evaluate first 4 or 5 times and then returns `True` indeed.

Comment: Yes, I have too

Comment: It is mysterious, the function PlanarAngle has values in [0, 2Pi], but function ArcCos has values in [0, Pi].